# compile error:A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, chess

when i compile the code below the compiler give the error:A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property in this code(which have stars)

```
 KingPiece kingPiece = new KingPiece(***siyahsah1***,ChessColor.White);
```

can anyone help me?

```
 class PiecePosition
{

    public enum ChessColor
    {
        White,
        Black,
    }
    public class ChessPiece
    {

        private Image DisplayedImage;
        private ChessColor DisplayedColor;
        private Point CurrentSquare;
        public Point[] ValidMoves;
        public ChessPiece(Image image, ChessColor color)
        {
            DisplayedImage = image;
            DisplayedColor = color;
        }
    }

    public  class KingPiece : ChessPiece
    {



        public KingPiece(Image image, ChessColor color)
            : base(image, color)
        {


            ValidMoves[0] = new Point(0, -1);    //  Up 1
            ValidMoves[1] = new Point(1, -1);  //  Up 1, Right 1
            ValidMoves[2] = new Point(1, 0);     //  Right 1

            ValidMoves[7] = new Point(-1, -1);  //  Left 1, Up 1
        }

        System.Drawing.Bitmap siyahsah1 = chess6.Properties.Resources.siyahsah1;
        KingPiece kingPiece = new KingPiece(siyahsah1,ChessColor.White);


    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not post unrelevant code, it makes reading difficult, the clas Board in your example is irrelevant to your question. Besides making Board class as nested to PiecePosition is a bit strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, siyahsah1 is a non-static private field, which cannot be used to initialize other fields. 
But you have another problem here. Because the `KingPiece` class has only one constructor, you cannot create a new instance of that class in the constructor itself - it will produce a `StackOverflowException`. Workaround would be to create another, private constructor which could only be called from within the `KingPiece` class. But better yet, maybe you could tell us exactly what you want to do and we can help you with that.

Update: Considering the comments I'm guessing that arash wants to specify the image to be used with the `KingPiece` class. If only one image is used independent of the piece's color, then you can just pass that argument to the base constructor.

```
public class KingPiece: ChessPiece {
  public KingPiece(ChessColor color):
    // Pass the image to the base class. All king pieces will use this image.
    base(chess6.Properties.Resources.siyahsah1, color) {
    ..
  }
}
```

But if you want to have different images for each color then that should be defined elsewhere or maybe as a static field/property.

```
public class KingPiece: ChessPiece {
  public static readonly BlackKing = new KingPiece(/* image of the black king here */, ChessColor.Black);
  public static readonly WhiteKing = new KingPiece(/* image of the white king here */, ChessColor.White);

  // Constructor could also be made private since you probably don't need other instances beside black and white.
  public KingPiece(Image image, ChessColor color): base(image, color) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks.i want to implement movements of king in chessgame with and put its picture in it.now can you help me?

Comment: @arash - Why do you need the kingPiece field?

Comment: @Patko:for all of valid movements of king

Comment: That's what the `KingPiece` class is for, I assume? But what about the kingPiece field, why do you need that for?

Comment: @Patko:to use the image of the king in it

Comment: can you tell me please how can i change the code till this code work?thanks

Comment: @arash, I have updated my answer. Hope it will help you. Oh and you should remove the `kingPiece` field (and probably the `siyahsah1` field as well).

Answer (score 4):

You should move the line into the constructor:

```
kingPiece = new KingPiece(siyahsah1,ChessColor.White);
```

The problem is that you don't yet have a class instance and the compiler doesn't like that. If you simply move the line into the constructor, it'll work.

You'll still have to define the property as a private field. You can do this with:

```
private KingPiece kingPiece;
```

Do this at the current location of the first line. The end result will be exactly like what you now heave, except that it will compile.

Answer (score 2):

The error is self explaining. siyahsah1 is a non-static private property of KingPiece and not is not initialized at the moment constructor is called.